# svg font overlapping letters interfere with fillrule

Tags: svg, fonts, webfonts, custom-font, svg-font

I'm making a custom font for the first time and I ran into a problem with the svg font. wherever the letters overlap, the `fill-type: evenodd` takes over. Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

svg-font code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<font id="icomoon" horiz-adv-x="1024" fill-rule="nonzero">
<font-face units-per-em="700" ascent="960" descent="-200" />
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="1024" />
<glyph unicode="&#x20;" horiz-adv-x="512" d="" />
<glyph unicode="&#x61;" glyph-name="a" horiz-adv-x="330" d="M244.507 684.815c0.887 3.646 1.794 7.292 2.726 10.938l53.835-0.183c-82.892-299.543-21.621-343.314 24.843-300.195 56.842 52.759 5.459-22.782-4.213-30.074-41.73-31.464-69.86-24.172-86.336 7.664-47.411-42.741-112.255-57.442-157.363-41.756-69.762 24.256-90.895 97.189-67.741 181.072 33.133 120.043 140.536 204.937 234.248 172.534zM226.571 594.306c-37.138 57.624-98.395 38.305-126.924 12.203-23.213-21.243-37.745-50.711-40.81-66.097-16.469-82.611 9.216-120.63 53.581-146.386 23.167-13.449 61.779-15.869 79.005-6.522 8.786 4.768 22.13 13.195 30.961 26.644-8.42 45.832-6.431 110.259 4.187 180.159z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x62;" glyph-name="b" horiz-adv-x="280" d="M11.453 630.31l-3.046-24.171 21.008 18.122c-68.882-253.654-1.357-288.441 47.215-300.204 42.845-10.383 178.959 41.002 201.337 235.23 32.892 0.666 58.068 30.599 79.311 52.73 65.066 67.776-24.622 17.847-42.571 17.263-15.582-0.508-30.85 6.139-34.744 11.66-0.437 1.112-1.291 1.978-2.361 2.39-1.070 0.405-2.257 0.323-3.261-0.233-23.559-13.129-44.13-37.376-64.949-64.816-1.252-1.641-1.663-3.825-1.102-5.844s2.015-3.626 3.907-4.306c25.443-9.119 14.408-72.246-12.34-144.148-8.427-22.654-29.539-37.218-52.635-36.319-32.918 1.394-70.565 19.605-83.179 48.59-19.815 45.513-14.936 125.423 17.167 242.729 157.213 171.327 177.23 281.464 157.044 292.602-15.243 8.412-128.072-42.952-199.902-319.946l-26.898-21.328zM90.249 708.716c9.529 33.558 13.638 53.204 34.294 97.591 23.474 50.437 44.919 102.927 54.768 101.437 13.827-2.088 11.479-29.102-1.409-60.655-23.865-58.43-60.201-111.888-87.653-138.373z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x63;" glyph-name="c" horiz-adv-x="260" d="M292.988 656.629c-13.677-26.963-36.838-45.199-65.060-62.797-37.105 58.205-98.623 38.853-127.23 12.679-23.213-21.243-37.744-50.711-40.816-66.097-16.462-82.611 9.222-120.63 53.587-146.386 23.167-13.449 61.772-15.869 79.004-6.522 12.699 6.894 34.933 21.432 39.277 47.756 20.682 10.586 34.679 13.801 61.329 35.286-25.385-114.375-143.699-163.794-214.028-139.336-69.762 24.256-90.894 97.182-67.74 181.072 38.925 141.025 180.36 233.55 281.677 144.345z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x64;" glyph-name="d" horiz-adv-x="340" d="M251.237 695.938c0.183 1.22 0.391 2.211 0.62 2.915 71.725 226.024 152.601 280.439 166.983 272.906 19.495-10.227 21.582-135.579-130.034-286.022-39.61-193.379-14.682-335.944 42.069-286.374 58.413 51.024 5.466-22.782-4.207-30.074-41.729-31.464-69.86-24.165-86.335 7.67-47.41-42.741-112.255-57.448-157.363-41.762-69.762 24.263-90.894 97.189-67.74 181.072 33.133 120.043 140.535 204.943 234.247 172.541 0.58 2.374 1.167 4.755 1.761 7.129zM231.539 598.299c-37.138 57.618-98.395 38.299-126.923 12.197-23.213-21.237-37.744-50.711-40.816-66.097-16.462-82.611 9.222-120.63 53.587-146.386 23.167-13.449 61.772-15.862 79.004-6.522 8.785 4.768 22.13 13.195 30.961 26.644-8.42 45.832-6.431 110.259 4.187 180.165zM291.264 710.678c27.452 25.156 63.788 75.933 87.653 131.431 12.888 29.976 15.236 55.635 1.409 57.618-9.849 1.409-31.294-48.448-54.767-96.347-20.656-42.167-24.765-60.827-34.294-92.701z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x65;" glyph-name="e" horiz-adv-x="270" d="M11.050 502.178c0.639 2.589 1.323 5.185 2.034 7.801 38.669 141.579 189.235 239.929 282.627 142.799 16.588-17.251 20.583-35.644 16.529-54.076-15.264-69.312-128.131-114.564-255.455-113.99 2.157-47.195 24.969-73.571 58.386-92.988 23.157-13.449 61.736-15.869 78.949-6.522 12.696 6.888 34.909 21.426 39.256 47.75 20.661 10.592 34.655 13.808 61.286 35.292-25.373-114.375-143.598-163.794-213.885-139.336-63.567 22.117-86.731 84.712-72.777 159.177-2.659 0.352-5.331 0.737-8.017 1.148l4.106 13.749c2.314-0.294 4.634-0.561 6.961-0.802zM224.289 604.076c-32.21 47.919-93.294 26.298-121.881 0.13-23.196-21.243-37.718-50.711-40.781-66.103-2.744-13.769-4.315-26.304-4.823-37.751 111.198 4.187 193.856 64.479 167.485 103.724z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x66;" glyph-name="f" horiz-adv-x="320" d="M73.359 631.948l-3.046-24.089 27.074 21.174c-7.97-58.44-20.552-112.495-20.552-112.495-58.74-30.417-77.009-96.274-76.128-125.295 0.594-19.56 17.532-42.787 50.691-51.982 0 0-14.382-89.897-17.917-122.613-8.055-74.524-24.857-229.559 12.692-254.018 22.522-14.675 43.093-13.779 60.781-5.063 39.577 19.498 61.779 63.968 68.191 75.776 132.422 243.906 58.107 389.062 58.107 389.062s53.842 37.252 60.436 44.306c36.877 39.469 106.607 179.562 7.468 61.806-8.655-10.283-57.077-62.039-84.386-83.275-23.617 36.869-51.252 68.34-96.471 78.999 0.104 30.479 14.219 75.339 21.1 142.946 157.207 170.695 178.946 293.678 158.76 304.775-15.236 8.381-128.066-42.794-199.896-318.773l-26.905-21.243zM185.073 383.232c74.811-129.003-10.247-343.983-78.144-370.221-88.762-34.303-59.686 49.539-9.346 322.919 43.034 8.579 50.672 18.226 87.49 47.302zM116.7 465.898c28.287-14.723 40.582-31.389 52.315-58.762-18.412-17.035-41.358-26.99-64.010-22.563l11.695 81.325zM62.447 406.862c-24.217 9.763-13.384 64.809 9.164 66.294l-9.164-66.294zM148.020 699.076c9.536 33.434 17.773 63.995 38.429 108.219 23.474 50.251 44.926 102.547 54.768 101.063 13.827-2.080 11.486-28.994-1.402-60.431-23.872-58.214-64.343-122.463-91.795-148.85z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x67;" glyph-name="g" horiz-adv-x="370" d="M190.337 345.637c-48.943-30.668-91.142-22.926-113.625-15.106-69.762 24.256-90.901 97.189-67.74 181.072 33.133 120.043 140.536 204.937 234.248 172.534 0.887 3.646 1.794 7.292 2.726 10.938l53.828-0.183c-18.302-178.906-19.671-192.695-31.998-287.281 31.45 18.223 38.931 25.424 63.768 43.106 25.254 17.988 44.299 32.311 59.607 47.652 22.619 22.665 42.904 38.547 45.428 33.792 4.129-7.807-42.669-54.696-56.046-67.747-25.802-25.163-76.93-61.173-114.27-86.877-5.472-68.608-13.801-146.315-24.25-224.413-6.953-51.924-10.755-97.71-29.683-134.079-22.998-44.195-37.49-50.841-72.463-62.718-31.64-10.742-47.039-2.289-60.462 6.020-94.697 58.616 36.831 326.010 110.931 383.289 3.059 1.918 6.144 3.985 9.249 6.209-2.961-1.657-6.053-3.737-9.249-6.209zM209.877 334.405c-34.972-11.121-107.089-185.69-105.093-245.969 2.296-69.078 54.513-93.738 65.608-76.063 18.732 29.826 31.6 218.399 39.486 322.032zM234.518 591.612c-37.138 57.618-107.631 40.321-136.159 14.219-23.213-21.243-37.744-50.711-40.816-66.097-16.462-82.611 9.223-120.63 53.587-146.386 23.167-13.449 61.773-15.869 79.004-6.522 8.786 4.768 18.68 9.973 27.511 23.422 2.713 40.986 5.903 59.959 16.873 181.365z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x68;" glyph-name="h" horiz-adv-x="280" d="M39.483 637.396l-3.046-23.697 21.008 17.766c-16.814-111.854-60.807-296.651-49.106-308.021 4.703-4.571 49.491 1.299 49.922 5.944 0.561 6.099 8.192 111.982 29.050 177.58 26.207 82.428 61.127 163.826 82.774 160.399 28.261-4.477 26.95-87.773 4.566-171.972-22.404-84.286-38.247-163.59-15.51-169.622 35.044-9.29 70.754 6.025 114.734 45.624 39.734 35.781 85.338 99.581-10.827 26.935-9.386-7.089-19.286-14.865-31.718-17.093-10.129-1.818-23.513 1.73-27.348 9.243-26.324 51.561 55.974 256.837-0.678 300.663-31.411 24.296-94.925-31.957-111.851-60.953 3.796 23.212 1.52 5.567 14.127 44.264 157.213 167.966 180.889 286.6 160.703 297.519-15.243 8.247-128.072-42.109-199.902-313.669l-26.898-20.91zM116.967 707.956c9.529 32.9 14.949 58.468 35.605 101.985 23.474 49.447 44.919 100.908 54.768 99.447 13.827-2.047 11.479-28.531-1.409-59.465-23.865-57.284-61.518-116.001-88.964-141.967z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x69;" glyph-name="i" horiz-adv-x="150" d="M0.808 460.201c11.284-21.315 106.509 66.338 106.509 66.338-21.458-100.587-51.526-190.242 1.109-201.128 24.654-5.087 58.897 7.22 92.356 29.631 43.96 29.494 50.874 40.458 46.635 45.382-1.957 2.283-29.611-15.914-43.113-22.508-13.958-6.835-30.003-5.081-42.591-0.894-71.224 23.611 33.394 238.572 23.154 246.275-7.305 5.479-36.916-12.21-58.831-35.396-16.045-17.043-22.698-35.892-41.286-54.676-40.438-40.986-86.747-67.76-83.942-73.024zM127.797 654.748c-1.044 1.402 1.239 6.209 2.739 9.855 28.503 69.188 44.874 78.776 87.203 91.423 5.805 1.735 14.349 3.548 15.654 2.074 1.304-1.481-4.761-6.927-7.827-10.925-29.481-38.879-22.763-47.593-31.698-57.246-12.001-12.973-35.547-27.146-57.005-33.746-3.652-1.135-7.957-2.844-9.066-1.435z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x6a;" glyph-name="j" horiz-adv-x="320" d="M164.685 366.104c0 0-14.414-10.899-22.959-19.436-66.267-66.182-203.496-325.704-108.792-384.32 13.436-8.309 28.829-16.769 60.462-6.027 34.96 11.877 49.439 18.523 72.463 62.718 18.915 36.375 22.698 82.161 29.676 134.079 10.436 78.098 18.784 155.805 24.263 224.419 37.308 25.698 88.442 61.707 114.271 86.877 13.371 13.045 60.136 59.94 56.027 67.741-2.544 4.761-22.828-11.127-45.395-33.792-15.327-15.334-34.373-29.657-59.614-47.645-24.85-17.688-28.242-25.587-59.679-43.81 5.87 59.816 37.96 214.792 32.872 218.445-7.37 5.355-30.394-12.21-52.309-35.396-16.045-17.043-22.698-35.892-41.286-54.676-40.438-40.986-86.747-67.767-83.942-73.024 11.284-21.315 106.509 66.338 106.509 66.338-12.784-54.35-20.023-136.107-22.567-162.49zM163.38 334.399c-7.892-103.633-20.741-292.205-39.46-322.032-11.088-17.669-63.332 6.985-65.614 76.070-2.022 60.279 70.115 234.848 105.074 245.962zM214.254 656.802c-1.044 1.402 1.239 6.209 2.739 9.855 28.502 69.188 44.873 78.77 87.203 91.423 5.805 1.735 14.349 3.548 15.654 2.068 1.304-1.474-4.761-6.92-7.762-10.925-29.546-38.879-22.828-47.593-31.764-57.24-11.936-12.973-35.547-27.146-57.005-33.753-3.652-1.128-7.957-2.837-9.066-1.428z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x6b;" glyph-name="k" horiz-adv-x="300" d="M82.261 498.215c55.028 18.251 48.918-159.347 83.627-170.096 33.211-10.278 51.672 0.901 92.785 30.065 43.447 30.821 88.612 89.574-10.754 22.181-6.834-4.635-16.421-8.29-28.585-9.447-13.7-1.307-22.19-0.392-31.75 8.78-17.308 16.598-14.503 54.388-22.2 83.566-13.233 50.187-22.578 80.355-47.415 74.203 0 0 117.183 128.628 83.309 154.828-31.292 24.202-94.162-31.909-111.022-60.792 3.781 23.119 1.512 5.545 14.078 44.091 156.616 167.328 180.197 285.51 160.084 296.391-15.179 8.215-127.578-41.949-199.139-312.48l-26.797-20.827-3.034-23.614 20.93 17.705c-16.752-111.428-60.578-295.527-48.922-306.856 4.691-4.556 50.612 1.358 49.735 5.923-5.391 27.96 7.468 104.898 25.070 166.381zM91.554 531.878c25.663 78.38 56.232 138.673 77.036 136.647 27.46-2.67-51.191-113.192-77.036-136.647zM115.672 708.962c9.494 32.777 14.895 58.248 35.475 101.602 23.381 49.258 44.749 100.524 54.556 99.072 13.779-2.044 11.441-28.426-1.4-59.243-23.777-57.068-61.287-115.563-88.631-141.432z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x6c;" glyph-name="l" horiz-adv-x="130" d="M12.474 631.271l-3.046-24.13 21.008 18.091c-68.882-253.221-1.357-287.95 47.215-299.692 22.509-5.45 70.754 6.128 114.734 46.45 39.734 36.435 85.338 101.408-10.827 27.427-9.386-7.218-21.139-10.852-33.316-10.379-32.918 1.392-70.565 19.571-83.179 48.507-19.815 45.436-14.936 125.209 17.167 242.315 157.214 171.035 177.231 280.985 157.044 292.104-15.243 8.398-128.072-42.879-199.902-319.401l-26.898-21.292zM91.27 709.543c9.529 33.501 13.638 53.114 34.294 97.425 23.474 50.351 44.919 102.751 54.768 101.264 13.827-2.084 11.479-29.052-1.409-60.551-23.865-58.33-60.201-111.697-87.653-138.138z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x6d;" glyph-name="m" horiz-adv-x="450" d="M99.999 621.061c20.151 18.777 44.080 59.399 50.525 62.928 6.593 3.611 30.523 8.909 36.449 5.631 5.927-3.285 3.482-0.714-0.815-25.306 21.262 26.625 47.932 29.21 82.455 24.837 42.006-5.325 59.193-44.138 50.155-100.626 16.521 56.91 47.858 94.396 95.939 95.45 28.3 0.612 50.451-14.193 60.601-28.632 21.114-30.162 18.299-91.349 1.778-160.031-10.001-41.424-23.040-93.043-10.075-112.071 12.594-18.553 33.634-12.888 57.119-0.864 43.339 22.178 48.154 12.949 6.223-27.040-19.41-18.492-45.487-35.337-81.196-30.087-36.449 5.366-35.782 90.2-10.372 179.516 25.411 89.214 7.186 146.538-25.040 146.321-25.855-0.17-62.971-44.076-80.381-130.631-21.114-104.604-21.558-170.158-28.967-187.098-3.852-8.828-50.822-10.426-53.563-6.862-4.741 6.243 74.232 323.796 5.334 324.047-42.228 0.163-68.083-86.398-80.603-127.897-21.114-70.205-32.375-181.705-32.967-188.173-0.519-4.917-51.34-11.14-56.748-6.298-9.557 8.671 25.855 186.663 46.599 288.159-2.148-0.85-115.052-93.641-127.869-71.416-3.112 5.481 49.488 33.406 95.42 76.142z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x6e;" glyph-name="n" horiz-adv-x="370" d="M103.418 621.961c20.781 18.972 45.458 60.015 52.105 63.581 6.8 3.649 31.477 9.001 37.589 5.689 6.112-3.319 3.591-0.721-0.84-25.568 19.864 31.045 86.485 42.589 123.31 16.581 42.020-29.705 24.601-112.264 7.564-181.651-10.238-41.86-23.684-94.007-10.39-113.24 13.064-18.745 34.762-13.021 58.905-0.873 44.694 22.414 49.66 13.090 6.418-27.321-20.017-18.683-46.91-35.704-83.659-30.399-37.665 5.422-36.978 91.135-10.772 181.377 26.282 90.145 20.399 143.364-12.759 148.154-25.289 3.669-58.828-47.515-89.541-135.764-24.372-70.225-33.387-183.589-33.998-190.124-0.535-4.968-52.946-11.255-58.523-6.363-9.856 8.761 26.664 188.598 48.056 291.147-2.216-0.859-118.65-94.612-131.867-72.156-3.209 5.538 51.036 33.752 98.404 76.932z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x6f;" glyph-name="o" horiz-adv-x="290" d="M274.918 669.742c47.548-33.928 48.526-135.157 36.59-190.981-25.959-121.523-160.84-173.997-231.15-147.985-69.789 25.81-90.921 103.386-67.767 192.619 38.938 150.025 160.057 219.407 262.327 146.348zM238.198 439.074c6.848 16.686 13.892 44.252 15.197 69.764 1.761 35.454-1.109 71.575-19.371 102.033-37.112 61.917-103.444 40.602-132.011 12.759-23.219-22.591-36.655-45.369-40.83-70.312-14.806-88.206 8.805-129.037 53.548-155.721 26.22-15.632 56.287-18.601 79.050-6.938 18.849 9.672 34.046 23.063 44.417 48.415z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x70;" glyph-name="p" horiz-adv-x="370" d="M105.847 619.437c21.313 18.972 46.623 60.015 53.44 63.581 6.974 3.649 32.283 9.001 38.552 5.689 6.269-3.319 3.683-0.721-0.862-25.568 20.373 31.045 88.701 42.589 126.469 16.581 43.097-29.705 25.231-112.264 7.757-181.651-10.5-41.86-24.291-94.007-10.657-113.24 13.399-18.745 35.653-13.021 60.414-0.873 45.839 22.414 50.933 13.090 6.582-27.321-20.53-18.683-48.112-35.704-85.802-30.399-38.63 5.422-37.925 91.135-11.048 181.377 26.955 90.145 20.922 143.364-13.086 148.154-25.936 3.669-70.522-45.193-91.835-135.764-19.433-82.965-77.418-546.878-79.533-559.432-0.784-4.941-52.5-8.72-58.768-3.889-2.743 2.151-33.302 46.746-31.578 66.048 0.627 7.016 32.518-19.762 33.459-12.444 19.041 143.749 73.029 521.186 90.817 604.378-2.272-0.859-121.69-94.612-135.246-72.156-3.291 5.538 52.343 33.752 100.925 76.932z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x71;" glyph-name="q" horiz-adv-x="350" d="M211.718 355.72c-44.938-28.248-97.965-35.605-136.12-21.21-69.071 26.076-88.312 99.537-62.94 182.787 36.264 119.13 145.838 201.18 238.65 166.332 1.109 6.392 5.218 10.436 6.718 10.462 6.979 0.13 34.764-2.211 39.786-7.259 4.892-4.937 16.24-50.202 29.676-73.219 30.589-52.4 70.832-91.808 66.658-96.452-17.088-18.817-95.29 97.952-96.986 99.282-0.326-4.161-63.462-528.547-74.55-608.302-0.978-7.292 32.807 11.61 31.568 4.683-3.392-19.065-40.503-55.511-43.373-56.979-6.522-3.307-49.439 11.734-48.917 16.697 0.913 8.479 28.894 219.788 49.83 383.178zM231.024 593.614c-35.612 58.577-97.378 40.875-126.532 15.53-23.806-20.623-39.068-49.706-42.59-65.008-18.588-82.148 6.066-120.825 49.765-147.736 22.763-14.056 61.309-17.486 78.789-8.59 8.936 4.533 24.719 7.768 27.198 23.663 9.849 62.262 12.849 103.117 13.371 182.142z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x74;" glyph-name="t" horiz-adv-x="150" d="M78.923 685.292c-22.111 3.418-44.286 8.544-48.852 7.344-6.848-1.82-22.828-24.713-26.22-30.824-0.457-0.874 40.895-4.67 66.723-6.327-0.848-3.118-1.696-6.268-2.544-9.444l-8.936-27.328c-68.875-253.228-1.304-287.953 47.221-299.699 22.502-5.446 70.767 6.131 114.727 46.452 39.786 36.434 85.377 101.409-10.827 27.433-9.327-7.22-21.132-10.853-33.264-10.377-32.938 1.383-70.571 19.567-83.224 48.5-18.849 43.275-15.327 117.721 12.784 225.893 36.916 4.050 124.836 14.956 118.64 34.242-1.826 5.616-49.504-6.822-105.791-8.525 149.491 165.718 168.405 271.895 148.577 282.813-14.479 7.983-117.14-37.966-189.016-280.152zM119.948 703.019c9.523 33.498 13.632 53.111 34.307 97.43 23.48 50.346 44.938 102.746 54.787 101.265 13.827-2.087 11.479-29.050-1.435-60.553-23.872-58.335-60.201-111.701-87.659-138.142z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x75;" glyph-name="u" horiz-adv-x="280" d="M297.376 326.435c-16.371 2.355-23.285 19.097-21.067 31.327-19.958-30.929-111.597-46.36-148.252-20.147-41.873 29.937-22.111 113.547-12.784 184.098 3.783 28.463 14.936 89.186 17.284 100.587-2.218-0.861-118.641-94.612-131.816-72.156-3.261 5.537 51.004 33.746 98.356 76.93 20.806 18.967 45.461 60.018 52.113 63.586 6.783 3.646 31.503 8.994 37.634 5.681s-10.436-105.942-26.35-186.753c-18.002-91.73-15.523-127.778 13.045-145.225 1.891-1.148 48.526-25.163 89.812 58.662 35.938 72.984 8.936 248.897 16.762 261.061 10.175 15.83 56.548 16.364 57.592 7.651 1.5-13.097-30.851-285.742-30.785-297.762 0.261-29.416 27.981-22.065 58.896-0.867 31.046 21.23 36.525 9.692 6.457-27.328-17.284-21.237-40.112-44.645-76.898-39.342z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x76;" glyph-name="v" horiz-adv-x="300" d="M335.761 617.271c-7.435-83.205-22.632-206.509-46.373-243.836-34.764-54.742-121.902-60.696-159.144-32.99-41.286 30.713-22.111 113.547-12.784 184.098 3.783 28.463 14.936 89.186 17.284 100.587-2.218-0.861-118.64-94.612-131.816-72.163-3.261 5.544 50.939 33.753 98.356 76.937 20.806 18.967 45.46 60.018 52.113 63.579 6.783 3.652 31.437 9.001 37.568 5.687s-10.37-105.942-26.285-186.753c-18.067-91.73-17.806-132.213 13.045-145.225 2.739-1.161 53.548-25.215 89.812 58.662 32.285 74.68 7.892 249.608 16.697 261.061 10.24 13.26 54.983 13.286 57.592 7.651 16.632-35.716 28.176-36.557 58.831-8.035 23.154 21.517 24.002 11.584 0.587-24.419-13.305-20.415-34.894-46.876-65.484-44.841z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x77;" glyph-name="w" horiz-adv-x="550" d="M260.515 417.245c0.652 33.544 9.131 72.11 13.827 107.657 3.783 28.47 9.783 69.762 16.893 89.245 5.348 14.499 40.569 15.784 46.7 12.471s-0.457-33.022-16.371-113.834c-18.067-91.736-17.806-132.213 13.045-145.225 2.739-1.161 53.548-25.222 89.812 58.655 32.285 74.68 7.892 249.608 16.697 261.061 10.24 13.26 54.983 13.286 57.592 7.651 16.567-35.71 28.111-36.557 58.831-8.029 23.154 21.511 24.002 11.577 0.587-24.419-13.305-20.421-34.894-46.882-65.549-44.841-7.37-83.211-22.567-206.515-46.308-243.842-34.764-54.735-121.901-60.696-159.144-32.983-5.674 4.2-10.175 9.379-13.762 15.367-40.308-38.41-112.053-40.19-144.925-15.725-41.286 30.713-22.111 113.54-12.784 184.092 3.783 28.47 14.871 89.192 17.284 100.587-2.218-0.861-118.64-94.612-131.815-72.156-3.261 5.537 50.939 33.753 98.356 76.93 20.806 18.973 45.46 60.018 52.113 63.586 6.783 3.646 31.437 9.001 37.568 5.681 6.131-3.313-10.436-105.935-26.285-186.746-18.067-91.736-17.806-132.213 13.045-145.225 2.609-1.122 48.656-23.409 84.594 50.046z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x78;" glyph-name="x" horiz-adv-x="360" d="M196.243 529.924c-41.938 94.58-78.919 121.654-106.443 113.468-9.849-2.935-50.548-17.617-62.614-42.167-20.415-41.469-30.72-26.115-16.762 22.13 8.675 29.787 44.678 83.433 93.138 76.187 49.569-7.403 93.203-69.325 125.097-140.901 3 2.478 5.087 4.103 6.196 4.735 31.698 23.487 84.985 84.288 116.423 113.357 28.894 26.748 32.35 20.617 25.502-9.823-4.37-19.73-9.979-46.66-16.762-54.031-0.978-1.076-51.917-42.688-114.922-93.921 18.458-46.334 40.112-98.187 62.092-109.842 23.545-12.549 37.894 5.205 50.026 31.040 22.437 47.652 32.872 40.601 23.872-25.104-4.174-30.387-15.001-72.437-49.504-86.844-32.024-13.377-76.898 69.397-119.031 164.329-96.79-78.581-205.973-166.697-208.126-166.853-26.024-1.918 119.227 138.129 191.82 204.239z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x79;" glyph-name="y" horiz-adv-x="400" d="M226.301 386.777c-7.37-4.275-13.371-7.718-16.632-9.335-13.958-7.027-29.937-5.228-42.591-0.919-71.223 24.295 42.656 306.456 32.351 314.375-7.305 5.644-23.741-1.658-45.656-25.516-16.045-17.536-45.069-108.796-63.658-128.124-40.438-42.18-86.681-69.73-83.942-75.139 11.284-21.932 106.509 68.26 106.509 68.26-21.393-103.501-51.526-195.754 1.109-206.955 20.545-4.362 47.678 3.684 75.528 19.798-69.332-85.582-184.516-323.985-95.682-380.554 13.436-8.55 28.829-17.248 60.462-6.194 34.959 12.221 49.439 19.060 72.463 64.535 18.915 37.429 22.698 84.535 29.676 137.963 10.436 80.36 18.784 160.318 24.263 230.914 37.308 26.449 88.442 63.502 114.271 89.4 13.371 13.422 60.136 61.67 56.027 69.703-2.544 4.892-22.828-11.449-45.46-34.771-15.262-15.785-34.307-30.516-59.614-49.032-24.459-17.953-28.111-26.1-58.375-44.314-0.391-0.101-0.783-0.248-1.239-0.436 5.935 61.777 47.287 266.725 42.264 270.477-7.37 5.51-24.524 2.664-46.374-21.194-14.871-16.221-50.743-237.538-55.7-282.939zM224.084 345.503c-7.892-106.635-20.741-300.67-39.46-331.361-11.088-18.181-63.331 7.188-65.614 78.273-2.022 62.025 70.115 241.652 105.074 253.088z" />
<glyph unicode="&#x7a;" glyph-name="z" horiz-adv-x="385" d="M226.773 318.889c1.304 0.92 2.609 1.839 3.848 2.772 3.196 2.002 5.805 3.933 7.957 5.785 32.285 23.624 67.506 51.024 87.725 71.295 13.371 13.429 60.135 61.675 56.026 69.704-2.544 4.898-22.828-11.447-45.46-34.77-15.262-15.784-34.307-30.518-59.548-49.028-23.806-17.447-33.851-25.639-62.223-42.812-5.935-1.167-31.307 19.039-28.828 22.495 7.892 17.551 155.948 273.812 181.646 324.902 1.891 3.698-6.066 8.459-12.784 2.902-159.666-132.95-237.085-34.444-264.544-4.618-18.262 19.795-49.635-11.323-48.004-37.392 0.065-0.796 7.175-40.699 5.544-67.434-3.522-58.335-21.002-109.294-15.393-111.623 22.828-9.431 38.612 131.568 38.612 131.568 0.522 0.065 1.044 0.13 1.565 0.209 39.395-29.116 112.966-42.76 197.169-6.079-12.849-22.606-25.046-45.134-38.025-66.971-28.241-47.391-53.352-104.67-79.376-152.55-44.678 4.84-77.941 19.332-96.921 29.031-29.676 15.158-41.221-39.923-17.414-73.030 20.61-28.62 72.723 12.138 93.399-0.952 6.457-4.096 25.633-15.556 24.915-15.967-124.119-71.276-238.585-301.369-73.376-359.639 126.402-44.567 290.307 195.427 143.49 362.202zM176.16 294.665c86.942-104.715 54.461-252.4-58.505-269.599-20.61-3.131-63.331 6.522-65.614 71.021-2.022 56.274 89.16 188.201 124.119 198.578z" />
</font></defs></svg>
```

Comment: Look at [MDN's  example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule#nonzero) with squares. Probably you have to change drawing direction? Cool font BTW!

Comment: I’ve had that page opened in a tab and hoped that there was a better solution, I’m now trying to reverse some paths using `https://aydos.com/svgedit/`. The font is my gf’s handwriting, she needs 14 customized sweaters for a fraternity so I told her “let me make a font, that’s easyer. I regret that

Comment: Sam, where are `r` and `s` letters? =))

Comment: @KoshVery we had some trouble doing those, they're finished now, I've also just finished converting all of the capitals to SVG, getting there :D

Comment: A fairly important note here: `svg` as a font format was deprecated years ago, and `<font>` was [removed from the SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-SVG2-20180807/changes.html#fonts) after it became obvious that SVG font technology was vastly inferior to what could be done with web fonts. Only safari still supports it, everything else _removed support for it years ago_, so if you're diving into making your own fonts, I would strongly advise you to generate a modern OpenType font with SVG table, if your glyphs are SVG, but otherwise just generate ttf/otf and derive a woff/woff2 from that.

Comment: Ah @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thank you, I didn’t know they removed that. I’ll have to look into opentype then. The reason I was using svg is that I simply alraidy know svg and could do some stuff with it since I’ve done some svg generating projects in the past and wanted a quick and dirty solution since I just needed the font to generate a set of pngs with names to put on sweaters. That’s why I now just wrote a script to put the svg glyphs in the right place with js and it took me less than a second to get a good result. Now I do still wanne dive into fonts a little bit more...

Comment: Is it still good if it doesn't work in most browsers though? =) That said, there's a pretty wide offering of free, as well as cheap (... and of course, expensive, but why go for one of those unless you intend to make some serious money), font making tools these days. Especially if you already have your glyphs in .svg format, importing them into any app or util that lets you do font building is pretty much guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted your font to `woff` format and it helped (run the snippet below):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('data:application/octet-stream,wOFF%00%01%00%00%00%00%1ED%00%0F%00%00%00%001%3C%00%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00GSUB%00%00%01X%00%00%00%3B%00%00%00T%20%8B%25zOS%2F2%00%00%01%94%00%00%00B%00%00%00VXG_%F9cmap%00%00%01%D8%00%00%00%E2%00%00%02%BAd%D9WAcvt%20%00%00%02%BC%00%00%00%1E%00%00%000%0Dw%FA%B0fpgm%00%00%02%DC%00%00%05%90%00%00%0Bp%8A%91%90Ygasp%00%00%08l%00%00%00%08%00%00%00%08%00%00%00%10glyf%00%00%08t%00%00%12x%00%00%1CF%9E%97qDhead%00%00%1A%EC%00%00%004%00%00%006%12%20%85%97hhea%00%00%1B%20%00%00%00%1F%00%00%00%24%07%2A%02%B7hmtx%00%00%1B%40%00%00%00%5E%00%00%00d.%5C%FF%9Cloca%00%00%1B%A0%00%00%004%00%00%004Q%F8YAmaxp%00%00%1B%D4%00%00%00%20%00%00%00%20%00%F2%0C%10name%00%00%1B%F4%00%00%01z%00%00%02%C1e%E3%DA%A3post%00%00%1Dp%00%00%00W%00%00%00%870%DE%23%C2prep%00%00%1D%C8%00%00%00%7B%00%00%00%86%E9EB%C0x%9Cc%60d%60%60%E0b0%60%B0c%60rq%F3%09a%E0%CBI%2C%C9c%90b%60a%80%00%90%3C2%9B1%273%3D%91%81%03%C6%03%CA%B1%80i%0E%20f%83%88%02%00%26%3B%05H%00x%9Cc%60d%BC%C58%81%81%95%81%81%A9%8Ai%0F%03%03C%0F%84f%7C%C0%60%C8%C8%04%14e%60ef%C0%0A%02%D2%5CS%18%1C%18%12%19%AA%98%83%FEg1D1g0%C5%02%85%19Ar%00%EF%24%0A%EF%00%00x%9C%BD%D1In%C2%40%10%05%D0%DF%B6%F1%80G%3C%9F%80%15%8B%1C%27%5B%920%0F%09%12%19%60%9DU.%0D%BF%AD%7F%80l%92%96%9EKU%EE%B2%5B%5D%00F%00%5C%9A%91%07%98%1F%18%D8%F5%CD%AA%19%EA.%C6C%DD%C3%23s%9F%D1%C0%C1%09%D7%DB%8D%F9%1C%E7%21r%0B%DFM%87%E8%B0%C7%E3%97%7D%04%08%11%B1%3FF%82%14%19r%14%98%A0D%85%1A%0DZt%E8%D9%E0%E3%EF%97q%5Co%E4%07a4%8E%934%CB%8B%09PVu%D3v%FD%3F%FC%FC%17%2B%B1%0F%F3%A0%CC%1Ej.v%0AO%E2%D0%B3%D8%A9%BD%08%27%87%85%D8%89.%C5%DE%ECJ%02ZKH%1B%89h%2B%9C4v%12%D3%5E%EC%E9%0E%92%D2Q2z%95%9C%DE%A4%A0%93%F0%A6q%96%92%DE%A5%A2%0F%A9%E9S%1A%FA%92%96.%D2%D1U%FA%3B%BEq%20%B7%00%00x%9Cc%60%40%03Q%40%08%04%CC%E9%8C%B7%FE%EF%FB%BB%8E9%E3%EFbd6%00%B30%0E%25%00%00x%9C%ADViw%D3F%14%1DyI%9C%84%2C%25%0B-ja%C4%C4i%B0F%26l%C1%80%09A%B2c%20%5D%9C%AD%95%A0%8B%14%3B%E9%BE%F1%89%DF%E0_%F3d%DAs%E87~Z%EF%1B%2F%24%90%B4%E7p%9A%93%A3w%E7%CD%D5%CC%DBe%12Z%92%D8%0B%EB%91%94%9B%2F%C5%D4%D6%26%8D%EC%3C%09%E9%86M%CBQ%7C%28%3B%7B%21e%8A%C9%DF%05Q%10%AD%96%DA%B7%1D%87DD%22P%B5%AE%B0D%10%FB%1EY%9Ad%7C%E8QF%CB%B6%A4WM%CA-%3D%E9.%5B%E3A%BDU%DF~%1A%3A%CA%B1%3B%A1%A4f3th%3D%B2%25U%18U%A2H%A6%3DR%D2%A6e%A8%FA%2BI%2B%BC%BF%C2%CCW%CDP%C2%88N%22i%BC%19%C6%D0H%DE%1Bg%B4%CAh5%B6%E3%28%8Al%B2%DC%28R%24%9A%E1A%14y%94%D5%12%E7%E4%8A%09%0C%CA%07%CD%90%F2%CA%A7%11%E5%C3%FC%88%AC%D8%A3%9CV%B0K%B6%D3%FC%BE%2Fy%A7w9%3F%B1_oQ%B6%E4%40%1F%C8%8E%EC%E0%ECt%25_%84%5B%5Ba%DC%B4%93%ED%28T%11v%D7wBl%D9%ECT%FFf%8F%F2%9AF%03%B7%2B2%BD%D0%8C%60%A9%7C%85%10%2B%3F%A1%CC%FE%21Y-%9CO%F9%92G%A3Z%B2%91%13A%EBeN%ECK%3E%81%D6%E3%88%29q%CD%18Y%D0%DD%D1%09%11%D4%FD%923%0C%F6%98%3E%1E%FC%F1%DE%29%96%0B%13%02x%1C%CBzG%25%9C%08%13%29as4I%DA0r%60%25e%8B%2A%A9%F5%AE%988%E5uZ%C4%5B%C2~%ED%DA%D1%97%CEh%E3Pwb%3C%5B%0F%1D%5B9Q%C9%F1hR%A7%99L%9D%DAI%CD%A3%29%0D%A2%94t%26x%CC%AF%03%28%3F%A2I%5Emc5%89%95G%D38f%C6%84D%22%02-%DCKSA%2C%3B%B1%A4%29%04%CD%A3%19%BD%B9%1B%A6%B9v-Z%A4%C9%03%F5%DC%A3%F7%F4%E6V%B8%B9%D3S%DA%0E%F4%B3F%7FV%A7b%3A%D8%0B%D3%E9i%E4%2F%F1i%DA%E5%22E%E9%FA%E9%19~L%E2A%D6%022%91-6%C3%94%83%07o%FD%0E%D2%CB%D7%96%1C%85%D7%06%D8%EE%ED%F3%2B%A8%7D%D6D%F0%A4%01%FB%1B%D0%1EO%D5%29%09L%85%98U%88V%40b%ADkY%96%C9%D5%AC%16%A9%C8%D4wC%9AV%BE%AC%D3%04%8Ar%1C%17%C7%BE%8Cq%FD_33%96%98%12%BE%DF%89%D3%B3%23.%3Ds%EDK%08%D3%1C%7C%9Bu%3D%9A%D7%A9%C5r%01qfyN%A7Y%96%EF%EB4%C7%F2%03%9D%E6Y%9E%D7%E9%08K%5B%A7%A3%2C%3F%D4i%81%E5G%3A%1DcyA%0B%9At%DF%C1%90%8B0%E4%02%0E%900%84%A5%03CX%5E%82%21%2C%15%0Ca%B9%08CX%16a%08%CB%25%18%C2%F2c%18%C2r%19%86%B0%BC%ACe%D5%D4SI%E3%DA%99X%06lB%60b%8E%1E%B9%CCE%E5j%2A%B9TB%BBhTjC%9E%12n%95T%14%CF%AA%7Fe%A0%5E%3C%F2%869%B0%16H%97%C8%9A_1%CE%95%8FF%E5%F8%D6%15-o%1A%3BW%C0%B1%EAo%1F%8E%F69%F1R%D6%8B%85%3F%05%FF%D5%D6T%25%BDb%CD%C3%93%AB%F0%1B%86%9El%27%AA6%A9xtM%97%CFU%3D%BA%FE_TTX%0B%F4%1BH%85X%28%CA%B2lpg%22%84%8F%3A%9D%86j%A0%95C%CCl%CC%3C%B4%EBu%CB%9A%9F%C3%FD71B%16P%FD%F87%14%1A%0B%DC%83NYIY%ED%E0%AC%D5%D7%DB%B2%DC%3B%83r8%13%2CI17%F3%FAV%F8%22%23%B3%D2~%91Y%CA%9E%8F%7C%1Ep%05%8CJe%D8j%03%AD%15%BC%D9%271%0F%99%DE%24%CF%04q%5BQ6H%DA%D8%CE%04%89%0D%1C%F3%80y%F3%9D%04%26a%EA%AA%0D%E4N%E1%86%0D%F8%05an%C1y%27%5C%A2z%A3%2C%87%EEE%EC%F3%28%A4%FC%5B%A7%E2D%F6%A8h%8C%C0%B3%D9%1Ba%AF%EFB%CAoq%0C%244%F9%A5~%0CT%15%A1%A9%185%15%D04Rn%A8%06_%C6%D9%BAmB%C6%0E%F4%23%2Av%C3%B2%AC%E2%C3%C7%16%F7%95%92m%19%84%7C%A4%88%D5%A3%A3%9F%D6%5E%A2N%AA%DC~f%14%97%EF%9D%BE%05%C1%2051%7F%7B%DFtq%90%CA%BBZ%C92Gm%03S%B7%1A%95S%D7%9AC%E3U%87%EA%E6Q%F5%BD%E3%EC%139k%9An%BA%27%1Ez_%D3%AA%DB%C1%C5%5C%2C%B0%F6m%0E%D2R%26%17%D4%F5a%85%0D%A2%CB%C5%A5P%EAe4I%EF%B8%07%18%16%18%D0%EFP%8A%8D%FF%AB%FA%D8%7C%9E%2BU%85%D1q%24%DFN%D4%B7%D1%E7%60%0C%FC%0F%D8%7FG%F5%03%D0%F7c%E8r%0D.%CF%F7%9A%13%9Fn%F4%E1l%99%AE%A2%17%EB%A7%E870k%AD%B9Y%BA%06%DC%D0t%03%E2%21G%AD%8E%B8%CA%0D%7C%A7%06qz%A4%B9%1C%E9%21%E0c%DD%15%E2%01%C0%26%80%C5%E0%13%DD%B5%8C%E6S%00%A3%F9%8C9%3E%C0%E7%CCa%D0d%0E%83-%E60%D8f%CE%1A%C0%0Es%18%EC2%87%C1%1Es%18%7C%C1%9Cu%80%2F%99%C3%20d%0E%83%889%0C%9E0%27%00x%CA%1C%06_1%87%C1%D7%CCa%F0%0Ds%EE%03%7C%CB%1C%061s%18%24%CCa%B0%AF%E9%D60%CC-%5E%D0%5D%A0%B6AU%A0%03SOX%DC%C3%E2PSe%C8%FE%8E%17%86%FD%BDA%CC%FE%C1%20%A6%FE%A8%E9%F6%90%FA%13%2F%0C%F5g%83%98%FA%8BAL%FDU%D3%9D%21%F57%5E%18%EA%EF%061%F5%0F%83%98%FAL%BF%18%CBe%06%BF%8C%7C%97%0A%07%94%5Dl%3E%E7%EF%89%F7%0F%DB%C5%40%B9%00%01%00%01%FF%FF%00%0Fx%9C%8DYi%8C%1C%E9Y%AE%EF%AB%FB%BE%EF%AA%3E%AA%BB%AA%BB%A7%A7%EF%9E%EE%B9%A7%C73%E3%99%F1%D8c%7B%C7%9E%B5%BD%5E%EC%BD%9C%DD%B0%5Eg%8Fl%12%E5%40%1B-%22%04%A1%84%90%28%24%02%A2%90%88%10%89H%1B%85%D5J%28%04%01%2Bq%08%F1%2FB%11%20%22%11%89%1F%09%BFP%A2%20%F0%9A%AF%AA%BBg%C6%87%02%2A%ED%B8%8F%EAV%BF%CF%FB%3C%CF%FB%BC%DFb%F0%DEO%EF%7D%0F%FC%17%F8%21%96%C3%BA%986%92%3B%3A%C461%0C%13%B1%5D%0D%90f%1D%0C%866ES%B6e%5B%C3%81%85%1EU%92%8A%04%D0%9Fd%B8%0A%86%03%1B%3D%A0%25%40%8Fo%C9%A1W%86%09x%12%C2s3%02%27%F2%9E%ED%97a%99%A9%17rz%E7%13%DD%1D%D7q%ED%177%B6%ABn%9C%2F%E5%9B%AA%8C%2B%96%DEwN%EB9I%03%7FKq%E0%8B%2F%5C%EF%D6i%CA%8D%94%01%5D%24%89R%A3%A0%B9%3B%5B%D7%2F%7F%D2%F7%BF%98%F0%2C%CF%CE%84%AE~%A9%D7%08e%92S%CDg%D0%AF%C4%E0%BD%FF%B9%F7%E70%C2%9F%C7v%B1%27%B0h%94%AF%40%80c%00lc%00%03w%D0%FB%D8%1D%0C%C2%5B%DDv%E8%AB%0AN%1Au%9D%1Ef%C5%A4%E5L%AF5%B0%9AUP%A2P5%95%28%7DHS%E8%0E%F4%CF%B8TT%EC%E4VT-5%B9%A6%9FE%7Fl%2B%7BI%21r%0D%02%2F%B9M%AF%DA%AAu%8B%15%3E%CCi9%2AOh%7C%90%A7%95%90%04%90%00%B6%AB%F98%81%7B%14%95gg%DC%B8X%12g7%CF%0F%5B%9EE%E0%02c8ATL%8AIx%06%27X%8AW%0C%87Si%19%CAN%5C%04%1F%8D%DCo%3CwP%F5yJ%92%CB%F5%B5%BD%A7%80%25%16%A9%82%89%E3%9C%008%1AB%20xz%89%E0%00%BB%3C8pB%005%23%F7%CC%CF%0F%2Fl-wKy%9A%60y%AF%D0%5E%3Cw%F5%CEEV%29jAiv%A0%E5%21%EC%94%96%E7%FB%29%8E%E0%DE%CF%10%0F%BE%0E%FE%11%ABc%FAH%09%88%23%16%D4k%00%C1%06%D2%02%1F%EE%F5%F8%CA%8A%1FS%02%DA%16%F8%9A%E4%1A%D1Q%8F%D5q%8F%3B4%A3h%BC%AAi%F3%DDS%EB%BD%5DD%05%F3%DAk%CB%23%F0U%DF%D6%CD%CA%B4%B9%07%FD%D9%1Cj%AE_%23i%86%E2%E4%FDAG%D32%0E%EC%7Dx%1D%27%D0%0F%C2Q%BF%DF%85%B7P%BF%5B%D8%06v%09%E3%DE9%BB%B9%D6%8B9%BCQ%07%FD%E1%DC%E4%17%8D%7B7%B9%D2%1F%3A%21%EE%D1%CFL%99%FB%88r%12%3D%FD%F8%2AH%BB%2Cg%25%83%F7%81r%AD%1C%E7%7CK%C3%09%9A6%EDdv%C5%24I%AD%9E%8Ba%3C%26%F6h%B5%B3%9B1%7B%F3%F4%BA%9B%95%DDPe%E2%98%DA%B7%F3%C5%D8AM%A4%15%CE1%15%1E%F1%FC%07%00%82%97%0Fw%3AU%5D%E1l%B7%5Ck%0E%86k%2B%CF%5E%BB%FC%A1%9AWT%06TF%7DEQ%BD%9D%CD%27S%EE%5B%9F%1C%E3%93s%8C%14%1F%29%25%FFS%60%3D%EC%CC-%14%DA%10%04Z%B7%1E%05j%01i%E1%BF%EF%FD%29%F8%1B%D4%C3Yl%05%8BGQ%BD%06S%29%E4%01%EA%25%40%3D%BE%84%9EaW%D0%03%EC%EC%C2%BC%AA%40%D4%D71%81W%81%3D%A5%7B%C9%9A%80%91%11%FBDk%A3%CA0%3EF%8CF%1F%82%0A%00%C0h5%3F%BC%B4%D6%8E8~%AE%F7%95%27%A0mT%9C%D3Z%876%0C%5E%D3%D5%F9%EE%C6%A8%7F%CA%F7d%9C%A1%C0%A2Y%CA%95r%29%25H%B80%D7%3E%ED%BE%0B%09rouy%83%24%BBQ%BD%9D%C4%D5v1%B4Qu%DE%0C%CBQ%9C%B2%3FL%9Bo%AF-%3F%06%F5%DF%2AP%94%20%A4%0CqC%A8%C8%8Dn%CAY%12%C3%EE~%0D%BC%87%B8p%11%7B%0E%BB%8D%BD%82%BD%81y%23%7B%29u%80%AD%DB%EF%1F%D6%242%23%F1%ADW%5E%06%13%E5%8F%9B%9Aj%DB%1E%93%23%B5%81q%A5%99%B8%D3%AB%052%0E%0C%07%13%02%A5%2F%F6%8F%CD%E2%84%03%E8%29h%29%1E%99A%8C%BF%A6%92~%B7%04Z%A0%89%9E%EA%27%0DB%02%2F%90%15Z%E0%2A%BE%25pH%9DE%9E%C7e%00J%B3%F5%C1%0C%88%1CK%E4I%12%02%82%A0H%92%A8%D6%28%BD%CD%F3%A2%DA%11%E3Y%2F%0C%CA%0D%5E%22%CF%0F%DB%BEE%10%C8%26%DC%20%2AT%90M%7C%24%C1%09%C7%3AS%AE%25%10%F2%B4%1DT%2C%25%3A%08UY4%DA%F6%8AB%EA%F2K%22%23%E9%9A%C7%A9%8C%04%25%F7%2C%F8x%94%EB%2Fu%8C8%17%E7%5B%86%CD%9E%3E%1B%BEy%F6M%3B%B4%FC%F3pme~%D0i%D6%2A%C5%9Cc%29%02%17%84%94y%21%C8S%F4%A2%924%8C%86%5B%E0%CD%95%DD%CE%E1%C1%F6%DA%20%29fv%92o%2F%9E%BDz%E7%BDO%AC_%3B%7F%F9%FC%07%25E%8B%8B%DB%8D%8F%7F%9E%11%D8%E0%0D%D9%D0%F2%BAJ%14%E8%C6%0C%00%A7Znm%26%99%D7%0B%00%F9%CD%CAG%91%86%FF%F3%EE%B7%E0%EB%E0_%B19l%1B%BB%81%D9%23%E3%C9%EDA%3F%A7%F1%F4%D4t%82t%F4%90%27%C4%3A%1C%F7%EB%88%AD%E9%B3%B4%99%12%9CX%F4%B0%8F%5E_%03%94%3Di%EB%B1C%E9%0F%E8%7C%DAn%A0%9C%3F%C8%84%7B%7Bc%7B%1D%3F%07t%8A%16%A2%C8%9E%0F%DD%18%A7%0E%AB%1F%E3%1C%C4Z%AE%E0k%E2%92-%19mP.%3C%5D%15I%C3IJ%BE%0F%80%C8%ABJH%A9%0A%27%96%DDjT%89Nh%1E%17%28%8E%81t%D0%0D%A7%D3%CBR%00%FB%BD%B9%E5%A7uO%AD%84n%40%F2%87%95%CB%9F%FD%B6%B3%1A4W%0B%1Cm%20%EB%0F%2Fl%DD%3C%FC%DD%3C%0Bmf%FB%D4%85K3%25%DF%91Ed%84_z%FC-%F0F%22p%3C%5B%0B%1Dc2%FB%20E%B2Ba%23%9B%7F%18%86%7C%FB%1F2%0D%3C%9D%3A%F7b%C6~%F4%8E%84%EDVS%14S%DA%8Fk_%05sc%0A%23%10%26%2F%A5%2A%9E%00%09%8E%A6%5C%A5%09N%0C%B8%FFk%EEI%60%9E%C8%B1%81E%F34%5E%2A%02%C9%CF%E7J%96.%F3J%40sV%7C%BEmUX%D5hS%02z%E6%10%1C%2AUH%19%3ES%CA%15B%11%07%90bRZ%3B%19%AD%A7%D3o%07%27x4%FDl%9BU%D2%E9%E7%EE%80_%8D%BC%A5%CF%BEV%DF%A6q%40%E3%D4%1F%1C%3E%BD%B6C%E0%DB%1FX~aq%17%B5%A8%AE7%3D%9A-%93%0CA%11%0Cm%F6%F2%7B%A7%8B%F3%D1LQ%12%02%CFVqRt%2F%3D%B6%B5%DA%8F%8B%14%E2%AD%9Bo-%EC%5D%B9%BD%CD%2Ae%BD%10%B5%BBj%80h%19-%BF%9Af%89%7B%F7%FE%02%BC%04%E7%90%7F%AEc%CC%DB%EBsE%116%EA%C3%CC%22%A6%AC%3A%C2%E2%18%AE%E4h%D4%D0%94%3E%E6%2B%9A8cP3%E2%01%BA%1A%D4%CA%92J%D24%93%F3%B6%E2%7D%1E%16L%DA%DF%C0%81%CA%3B%02N%E1%CC%9C%CD%CB%BA%94%9F%D7%29%F6%1D%9C6%8A%A6%12%998%87%AB%2C%C5%90b%D3%12%3E%25%3AZ%29%3F%DA%2B%F4%FD%02E%DAn_%84%9A%40%88V%BF%B6Y%D9.%0B%06%A4%0A.%EF%84R%BE.%91%0C%D0q%BE%D3%119%8EDx%DB%1A%E7%91%92O%13%E9%EC%BC%87t%D7%83C49%0F%B1%17%D1%EC%7C%F1%E6%DEfKF%B3sx%A2%84q%95%AB%F0%3Ec%3Cr%FD%FB%B9p%E4%A0Sg%CDp%99%06%26%3DI%93%D5%83h%FC%98%22E%26nv%F31%00-%5D%B2%97D-%28%B0%A8y%B6%B0%98%EB9%87%14%8C%7B%CB%82%EA%87D%8A%0Dd%2C%DD%CB%C0Y%D4%28%060%95%B0VVd%02%09%90U%14%2A%27k%BC%08%40%E0%95%93%9B%80%00F%84%803p%9A%D4X%92%25%A4%A6%C5C%92%E0%99%F8%DCc%0776%F7C%01%27%0C%9A%2B%AC%CC%FAK%F9%3F%FAR%D5J%9CC%9E%0C%FA5V%B2%D5%DA%A77%DC%0A%A4%14%C9Oq%2C%CCJ%04%033%D07%3E%B7%CEY%DF%3A%F8%9C%C7%91%A2%EC%F8%A5%99K%17Nm%83%EFC%1EL0%A6iG%E3%5CR%0A%A8%14c%A4%C7w%C1w%91%1E%2F%23g%FB%00%16%8C%DC%DD%9DVD%A4%92%04%28%8B%02%20%81%DD%8B%E7mk%3C%7C%C7It%C2%ABL%8B%E9%D5%04H%82%29%88%F4%7D%E2%7B%B4%1EexB%DF%C9X%DF%99%3D%3E%A4%D3%D7MY%E4h%8E%A7y%C9%8Em%25%B2k%9CnvUG%D1MDAB%E5%14%C7%CD%D9yAV%CDR%F8%B0%3A%5D%7F%AC%CE%E4H%EE%E5%02e%15%C30gi%A6Z%8E%A4%B1j%15%8F%D3%B2i%B3%F3%3DZWJV%BBo%14I%9A%14Y%5B%A994%5B%14%00%2A%DD%14%97%A55%23%A4%C2ra6%97%88%8A%24%84%EED%A9%17%91R%CBS%A5%CE%EF%3D~%3B%17y%CB%9Fy%AD~%9A%C6%21%8D%87%BF%F9%EA%D5%FE%02%84%F5r%B7%F5%E3%B1%84%A3y%A3%90I%F8%95l%1Fx%0Fi%F8i%84%FF%2C%B6%8A%A9%23%09%02%98%D9%E1-S%07%0F%C6%FF1%DE%A5%FF%7F%C0%D7%88%5C%93%C0%CBN%D3%AFwgSc3%DBz%10%17%CBb%FDD%86%9F%0E%E73%90%401F%D5%5D%5EI%F1H3%FC%C7%22%0Fe%F8%8A%CF%D3%B2V5Z%1E%C3%C6r%9A%D3%9F%FD%19%CA%E9K%BD%28%3F%1D%ACiN%A7%A5H%CB%95kC%3D%0FN%E4t%C4%AF%BF%C4K%E0%FB%D8%B3%D8WF%A2%88%AA%BB%F1%C4%AEA%00%02n%EF%BD%E5_%B82%2Ac%04L%17%8D%DB%18%40q%82%FCe%B4%FE%A4%99%0F%13w0%92%94v0%1C%97%F0%5D%7F%EF%AD%26%BA7z%F0%5E%04%20%81%C1%9B%27%EF%7C%F8%0BI%1C%92%F8%F1%BD%D9mW%AF%8E%E4%C3%CBg%CFlm.%0C%E3%B2kS%29%D6%E30%9D%0790%B6%0E4w%E8%09A%11E%8D%2C%89e%EE0%0D%99%E8%F1%5C%3F%29E%C7%F6%82%C6RzGi%B2%94%D1F%3A%ED%C7~%3C%EE%D9g%D4%82N0%09%85%D4%0Fqh%E6%9D%99%D9%98%D3%8B%A5n%E0%99%82%054%99%A4%1D%5B%0B%5B%D4%AC%EB%14J.%C7%F2%9A%9A%B3%F5%86f%0A%AAH%13%B8%AE%C48%9F%A3%84n%25%D2m%5Df%C8%A4%8A%B3%AE%1C%01%EE%F7d%C8S%D6%08%BC%247%7DH%A0%C9%03qJ%E4%7D%1AM%AFs%AB%A3%12r%2F%89W%F3k%0B%FB%2B%F9n%19%A0%06%9B36JiDRzu%7D%A5%DB%98%ABW%1BK%97_Y%E4%28%1C%07%E4%E2%D7%2F%7Fy%2B9%BB%F6%C2%A0%85%D3%10g%3Ew%F1%8FI%E6%23%3E%CE%90Jc%DA%D7%BF%82g%C0%3F%A3%04T%1FU%D7%96%91%FA%B0%3E%DA%13%60%BA%C9%A2%18%0Fo%8F%7B%08%A1%04w%87%830%98%AC%B3%F7a%7C%94%E3%CD%13%D0N%80M%8E%E6%949%01q8%C5%F0%F3%C84%09%B62%C1PB%B5yU%1C%3A%0AA%BB%B6%1Ev%A8%E6p%E4q%1C%AF%07%5C%D9%DF%2C%2A%02K%91%95%1A%C1%FAZQ%FE%7D%05p%94%B9%09%EE%C8%CD%E0%18%24%CB%C1%A1%16%5C%E8%3F%03%D7%C2n%0C%81%8C%B0%99c%89%A4%FC%DA%FA%CD%3B%24%F1%BE%1B%8D%CD%EE%7C%9DK%91%60%BF%F0%FC%97%F9%D7%3D%C8%90r3%D3%EF%CF%91~%FF%1A%FC%3Bf%A1%0D%8Fy%BB%5E%B0%044%83%01%2A%CB4%26%8C8%96%AB~%14%DB%8FF%D78%F4%81_%2F%C8%12%2BV%CB%FD%CE%AD%24%0Dy%C1%EA%F2%DE%BE%CE%A0%85%8E%2C%BAI1.%D8%3DF%B6%B4~%B0%ECZ%92%0A%BEc%F5%1B%8B%BD%D9%D5%EEl%E8K%92%7Fn%F7%E9%F7o%AC%F3%FC%7Bo%EA%5E%E8%5D%1B%D6%04N%E0%AC%5E%F7%DA%A0%95WQ%7D%B26%E9%D9%DD%B7%E1U%F0%03%EC%00%AB%8D%92%FD%DD%B4g%AB%8F%EC%99%0Cw%E7%87%5E%0B%27%ADi%C7%EC%9Ee%9C%E8X6%3E%1F%12%C3%B4g%28%12P%D1%D8%A6%FA%A8%C2%D4%BCtm8%BE1%FD%CC%17%B5%C8%24%98Z%DA%40%02%CA%A7%CA%89W%C3%A1%0B%15%9C%F6%1C%3D%D7%A5%5B%BE%1B%C5%3E%C7%09z%C8%97%F5%9E%E5%CA%D6E%AER%A3y%91%E5%00M%DA%24%0D%DCjK%C5%873%8F%F1%29%E9O%83%17%E5F%00I%9A%808%9D%B6%13B-D%EDdW%FCVFu%A3%EE%F0%22%89WJ%1F%5C%BF%F9%12%89%02Dk%F5%C6%DDO%9F%C1IR55%5B%C4%11%8B%20%8E%7F%17%98%60%F5%22%9C%F1%FA%FAq%7F%7Fv%F7O%E0%1C%F8%21%CA%FE%E70c%A4%A2mB%20%A6%B1%BF%99%C5%FE%93%C7K%AB%A0%D7%CD%2A%1E_i%C1-%40C%DA8%B1%A1%25sY%D6xT%CA_E%11%A3%FD%C2%CC%8Ec%05%DE%9D%CD%EDu%F4QA%B5%18%5E%E3%ED%16r%06%28%CD%A1q%A6%9C%17h%C2%21h%80%07%16K%AFA%C7m%3B%E5%7C9%DFD%E6%A1%99Z%CF%D9%D2i%91%E2%21%C7%889E%0Ev%B7%AE_%FA%15%D7u%28%16%E9%B8%D0%D3%ABK%06zS%5E%8B%06%D4%9Bw_%BD%84%03%C0%02%80%ABE%97%C6-%92%7B%FB%5D%F0%D3%8A%C0ql-H%D7%F7F%5E%A69%04%13%23%9C%BA%3D%CD%EF%EF%80%DF%C0%7F%09m%EC%E7%B1%F5%11%C7%20%E6%80%ED%2A%80%5B%7Bo9%C8%A2%11%D3%D2%11%96%BA%2Fx%091I%84%C8%92%25%F49xg%9A%28n%5D%7Dg%B6%9E%CFyx%9A%F6%8F%B4%90n%B8%0FL%BAi2%9B%DC%F2%D0%C4%B3%1F%1Ax%2FKN%40%D0%92%40%80%D3%9E%DAx%60%F4%99%5E%3A%FAjK%DFa%81%C08%EB%B5%BD~%C31%D1%08%A4u%DB%CB%E7%CB%85r%F8%F0%04%FC%3B%B4%F3%03%A0%29%2C%A0%C1%DC7%9E%7B%AC%8Af%A12%9D%85%2A%A2%99%9E%BB%F1%23%23D%20%E2%2C8%D8%DFX%E8%14s4%C1pVP%EFn%EC%EF%9E%9C%89%DD%D2%F2prvu%0Fy%E7%10%FC%0Bv6%3D%F5%40%22%04%60%5BE%08%A6%C8%DD%99%1C%04%A6%FB%D0%F6%E9%CD%8D8E%89l%82%A14%0EYY%BD%E3x%7F%1C%02%10o%C6%A7%21%27%0E%0A%2B%C9%5C%7Fr%B6%84Sf%06%EA8%F2%82o%22%2B%96%0E%EA%AD%0EK%11%10%FD%A7AbP%3D%9F%09i%23V%8A%26%B2VA%14t%91TLZr%ED%A2g%13%90%84%906%B5%12%8A%AE%2Ap%AD%D8%D2y%D35rC%18%C8%16Z.Kq%BE%13%ACTKO%09%F8%8C%DF%1D%8B%A7%A8%CC%22%3Ci%EA%EA%FE%CD%8D%8B-%91%04P%B1%06%AD%A7%86%CF%C6%A2A%F0%24%81S%FC%3D%ECw%E8%1C%0E%5C%19%84%5E%28%EA%C7s%E5q%F0o%28%04%A1%B9%A2%23w%AAZ%88%3Cp%1BY5%04W%10T%C8%A02t%D0%DF-lky%C9%22%D2c_jz%B0q%7C%B4%F1%08%842%9E%F5%1EB%28%07%C6F%06~%C8Kz%B3Y%BB%E6%3B%0C%85%23lp%8E%21%D8%AF%A9%C7%D00%D5%14%1A%09%12%AA%05%5C%A7%957%90%E3%20%CF1%B4%12%14%AC%C0r%81%5B%07%CF%BFz%F0%CA%AE%AER%86V%CE%B5%C2%A5%D9%60%AE%A5%D0%1F%0B%8EQA%7B%15Be%B3Zo%B3%1C%23%ED%B4%9E%1C%3CS%95%2C%82%25%08Hx%1Ao%3AF%E5%D4Qv%1A%82%1Fa%CFc%EDQ%E3%0C%92%D5S%9B%CBJ%9Ag%90c%9FD%03%BF2N5%0B%F3%9Dv%5CvR%40%E2%C1%D4Q%8E%DC%FAQ%DC%C8%2A%CF%06U%E5%C4%3E4%CE%F4%BF%90kGH%82%D7%80%80%8C%99%90%85%3C%87~%04%8B%CCT%B18%C9%B3%0B%F6%FD%E0%D8%AE%ABk~%88%10%B6%9C%14b%8E%0Dj%C9%B9%16%83L%9B%A1H%15%C7%87%B5%FD%8C%84%A7R%A4I%1A%21%CD%EBR%FAm%C0%B6g%F7%A2%DD%E6%F52G%92%80%F2%F5%ED%FAV%A5%DEb3N%CD%3D%00%9F%60%DAF%12%CA%16%7C%E5%F2%CB%E5XWI%83%96%3D%81g%CB%E5%7C%3B%5C%AE%15%9F%D4%F0%19%AF7%E1%A8%DC%C8%BAq%E5%EC3%E8%0B%DB%2CK%09%99%3E%FF%E3%DE%9F%C1%19%C4%C15%8C%FA%CE%40%05%8Dz%3C%B5%A9I%BE%9BlB%C3Ao%7C~%9B%05%18t%1D%9F%D4O%C7bzJ%8F%40rfj%E5%A2i%95P%F5%80%A3U%D3%CB%15%BA%9D%99%04%27%81%7F%A6%A5%E5%24%84%02%0Aj_%01%BE%EC%9A%B6.%C9%8E%C1I%F3%85v%3C7s%17wn_%F8%C9%8DZ%09%FD8%DD%0E%B9%B8%E8x%A1%A2%93%CCb%EF%12%24%8Cs%1D%25%60%22%98%93%1C%9A%7C%03n%84m%5E%90%F8%7C_%DBz%CE%11w%17%5E%8F%FE%1E%DE9%18%FB6%DA%A5%3F%85f%FF3%D8%EB%989%D2%1E%8B%D1%9Eq%AB9%3E6%BF%A5%A7%83%2CF%BF8%3A%3E%3C%BC%EF%9C%E0xs%9E%AE%DC%D3-%EE%17%AD%DF%91%F9%88%05%FC%81%A5%1Bl%C8%8CT%90%8B%C0%10%7C%89%40%8B%5D%C9%A2EZQ%19%89%CD%2F%E8%24%7Bt%18%C1%D0L~%E6T%B5%D6%F4%F3%104N.%E2%96%F8%A1%D9%C0%2C%11x%D2Y%964%D7%83D%5EF%EB0%AB%E8%16%A7%CB%AALO%B7oEM%B7o%DF%2F%25y%16%E1%CD%AF%F7%AF%F4%AE%B7%14%17R%9A%CBxrRUC%AE%D0%90H%06%97%5C%AD%5CX%DB%2F%CE%85E%8AK%DA%E7%0E%CE%3F1%DA%CD%16r%86%2B%AE5%82%D5%FC7%BFz0%1B%B8%15%86%0C%7B%0DN%B1dP%7F%EBr%AE%07i%B4%5EsO%EC%DC%BA~%93%B7%BF%7D%F8%05%9F%23%24%D9%0D%CA%F5%C3%83%CD%DD%2CO%FC%F4%EE%1F%C2%04%FC%13%DA%B6_N%FF%FF%CF%9A%02%91%E1o%2F%CEU%F0%FBv%EE%9D%D3%F3%C3t%E7%26%A7%B0%A6%A0f%3A%9E%100%99N%C8%16%40%EF%D8%A6u%B2I%BD%B4A%D3%D3%E0T%F9%C3n%FA%99%3C%18%9F%FFf%FDK%03%09%FA%BC5%19%9D%93%8E%A0%04%B2%89%12%D3%958%054%3D%D9%D0%92%22%15C%F2%D9_3%A0D%9F%DD%5C%E8VK%86G%09E%07p%10%97%D0p%84%92%C4%B34ln_%BC4p%9B%A1%B4s%CAp%09%85%B7%A5%9C%C5%2A%28%B4%82%8DW%DD%C0r.%CD-%0E%AF%19%A6%AC%BE%D9P%157%A9.i%9A%23i%10%94%0A%8F%9F%02%80%5B%8F%A7%60%8A%A1%0EB%82%FF%F6O%AA%24I%8DL%5D%60%029%A4D%A1%AC%E3%CB%C5%C6%B6%CD%F0%80%EADK%FD%12I%C57k%D7%17%7C%3A%E2%8A%8B%B6%02X%0A%AD%EA%9C%00%92%DF%DE%3F%5C%DB%09u%D7%F9%C0%CE%B9%BD%83%E2%60%7D%F5%B5%A4%C6B%8A5%BD%99ds%E5%F6%FF%0299%9C_x%9Cc%60d%60%60%00%E2%B8%ED%27%5E%C4%F3%DB%7Ce%E0f~%01%14a%B8%3EM%F12%94%BE%F2%FF%ED%DF%C5%CC%2F%983%80%5C%0E%06%26%90%28%00%9Ez%0F%0Cx%9Cc%60d%60%60%0E%FA%9F%05%24_%FC%7F%FB%DF%9B%F9%05%03P%04%05H%02%00%A6Q%06%E6%00x%9Cc~%C1%C0%C0x%FD%FFW%C6%09%FF%FF0%16%FF%FF%C6%F8%14H7%FE%FF%CDx%92%81%81I%E0%FFg%C6%09%0C%0C%0C%D7%FE%FFg%3C%09%C4k%80%EC%9D%FF%FF15%81%E4%80%FA%E6%FD%FF%01%A6%BF%FC%FF%C6p%0DHO%80%A8a%16%04%CA3%FD%7F%CBd%0D%A4%D5%FE%7F%05%00%F8%A5%28%FF%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%60%01%04%01X%01%E6%02%5E%03%3A%03%E0%04%86%04%F6%05%A8%06h%06%D8%07%C4%08H%08%9E%098%09%C0%0Ab%0A%F0%0Bv%0C2%0C%9C%0D%60%0E%23%00%01%00%00%00%19%00%82%00%05%00%00%00%00%00%02%00%0C%00%1C%00s%00%00%00T%0Bp%00%00%00%00x%9Cu%90Mj%02A%10%85%DF%F8%17%E2%40%16%09%04%B2%EBU%A2%04%C6%1F%10D%B2%10%04%85%EC%E2B%08d3%EA%FC%C98-%3D%AD%E0%25r%87%1C%24W%C9Y%F2%9C%29B%22%C4%A1%E9%AF%5E%BD%AA.%0B%C05%BE%E0%A0%FC%0DxJvp%C1%A8%E4%0A%F9I%B8J%9E%08%D7%C8%CF%C2u%B8x%11nP%7F%13n%E2%11%2Ba%177xg%07%A7v%C9h%83%0Fa%07W%8E%2B%5C%21%DF%09W%C9%0F%C25%F2%40%B8%8E%5Bg%22%DC%A0%FE%2A%DC%C4%C2%89%84%5D%DC%3B%9F%13%BD%3B%9A%24%8A%ADjM%DA%AA%DF%ED%0D%D5%F2%A84%A5%24%F3S%E5%EFm%ACM%AE%C6%2A%D4%99%0D%D2T%7B%2B%BDMx%B4%CE%E6A%B4O%7D%23%91%5C%8B%C0%E4%89%CET%CF%EB%8A2%0B%B2%C0%F86X%9F%3A%E7%87%A8om%A8B%A3%B7j%2A%3D%D5%CE%E8M%B0%B2%5El%EDn%D4%E9%FC~%8B%AB%D4%D8%E1%08%83%04%11bX%28%B4%A8%B6y%F7%D1E%0FC%D2%92%0EEg%E9J%90%C1GJ%C5%C7%9E%15q%91%C9%19%8FyBF%19%D5%80%8E%94%ECq%FD%1A%5BV%95%B7.%F2s%E6%23V%A7%ECa%CEr%7F%A3%05%9D%A7%EEI%11%29N%E4q%AE%BF%9E%19%3DY%E1%F3%8B%97%D7%3F3%E78%F0%9D%3EU%CB%C9N%D3%99%A2Naz6%A7%E2%1EN%B9%0D%95%15u%AF%D8%86%A5%3AB%87%DF%3F%FF%EB%1Bp%DE%80u%00%00x%9Cm%C1E%12%C2%00%10%00%B0M%F1%E2N%F9%1DR%5Cg%F0%D7s%E0J%12I%FC%A4%F1_%26QPTRVQU%93%AAkhji%EB%E8%EA%E9%1B%18%1A%19%9B%C8L%C3%CC%DC%C2Rnemckg%EF%E0%E8%E4%EC%E2%EA%E6%EE%E1%E9%E5%ED%13%F1%05xK%0B%EF%00x%9Cc%F0%DE%C1p%22%28b%23%23c_%E4%06%C6%9D%1C%0C%1C%0C%C9%05%1B%19X%9D6%0932h%81%18%9B%B9%D8%189%20%2C%21%160%8B%CDi%17%D3%01%06F%06N%20%9B%DDi%17%83%03%84%CD%CC%E0%B2Q%85%B1%230b%83CG%C4F%E6%14%97%8Dj%20%DE.%8E%06%06F%16%87%8E%E4%90%08%90%92H%20%D8%CC%C3%C6%C8%A3%B5%83%F1%7F%EB%06%96%DE%8DL%0C.%00%19%02%24%17%00') format('woff');
  font-weight:400;
}

body {
  font-family: "icomoon";
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Comment: thank you, the problem is still standing with svg fonts so I'll have to find some tool to combat that

Comment: @SamApostel, I'd suggest trying [Fontello](http://fontello.com/). Let me know if you need any help with that.